# Map3d with MapControl on c# WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I am trying to create a standalone application for 3D Map like Aerial3D of Bing for the UWP MapControl.
I tried a WPF Control into a WinForm c# application but the control does not have the style Aerial3D.
So I developped an UWP MapControl example that works but only when I run it from the VisualStudio 2017.
I am not able to convert the UWP into a standalone application by using Desktop App Converter.
I would prefer a classic WinForm / WPF application.
Is there any way to have the 3D view on a WPF MapControl?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the UWP MapControl (or any UWP control for that matter) in a WPF app process. Support for this scenario is on the backlog, but not available in current builds of Windows 10 (1803).

For now this control can only be used in a UWP app.

The DesktopAppConverter won't help here, as it is actually about migration in the opposite direction: moving from Winforms/WPF to a UWP app package.

Comment: Thank You.
So UWP is the only way. 
Now I have to understand how to create an application stand alone from UWP without passing through the market.

Comment: Ask a new question for this